# Axios response object key value is undefined

Tags: php, json, axios, undefined

I am trying to access an object `key` but it returns `undefined`. Here is the code

```
axios.post(url, {section: allSection, numero :'806UAB51251'})   
.then(res => {
  console.log(res.data.firstname);
})
.catch(function (error) {
  console.log(error);
});
```

when I do `console.log(res.data);` It gives me

```js
{"firstname":"Lilo","lastname":"CHAPE","section":"","number":"21299345"}
```

But `console.log(res.data.firstname);`  is giving `undefined`.

Code from php server:

```
function displayCard($section, $firstname, $lastname, $number, $groupe) {
 $data=array('firstname'=>$firstname,'lastname'=>$lastname,'groupe'=>$groupe,'section'=>$section,'number'=>$number);
 echo json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
 ...
}
```

Comment: Try `console.log(JSON.parse(res.data).firstname)`

Comment: @PrathapReddy the default for Axios is to parse responses as JSON so I'd be awfully surprised if that works

Comment: Looks ok to me from what you've shown. Two things you should do though... 1) Add `header('Content-type: application/json');` before your `echo`. 2) Add `exit;` after your `echo` to make sure you're not accidentally outputting anything other than your JSON

Comment: @Phil, It's a guess. Since everything looks ok there. I thought it might be coming as a stringfied value, that's the reason why it become `undefined`.

Comment: Thanks for your Help, when i do ....  "console.log(JSON.parse(res.data).firstname) " ...   it return :  .....  "JSON Parse error: Unrecognized token ''
Stack trace:
  [native code]:null in parse "..... also @Phil i did exacly all your recommandation but still have undefined ....

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was indeed the json, i posted the code somewhere else and noticed missing character `" { "` when i `output` the json so i did :

```
var badJSON = response.data;
    var obj = eval( '(' + badJSON + ')' );
    console.log( obj );    // Logs: Object {a: "b"}
    console.log( obj.firstname, obj.lastname );
```

Problem Fixed !